# snap starts plexmediaserver service as root

Tags: snap, plex

I installed plex media server with snap. Now I realized that the service is running as root.

- Is this the normal behavior?
- Is there something like a config file for snap where I can change the user which starts the service?

I did not find any usefull information about this topic in the snap documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by access media outside the sandbox? I can serve content from "anywhere".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's normal behavior for snap at the moment. Here are further details to this topic:
[here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1619888) and [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/multiple-users-and-groups-in-snaps/1461)